# multiple group by for a table query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:

```
    Month     Type        Price    
    ============================
    1          a           12     
    2          b           43
    1          a           11
    4          c           22
    1          b           33
    2          c           4
    3          a           25
    2          b           35
    4          c           20
```

I want to get a query that has result some thing like this:

```
    Month     Type     Total Price    
    ============================
    1          a           23     
    1          b           33
    2          b           78
    2          c           4
    3          a           25
    4          c           44
```

means: 
prices are Total Price of special Type in a Month.

for example we have type 'a' in month '1' and '3'
Total Prices of 'a' in month '1' is 23 and in month '3' is 25

I think we should use multiple group by.
I can group it just by Type or Month but not by both of them.

thanks for helping

Comment: *I can group it just by Type or Month but not by both of them* why not?

Comment: Could you show us your attempt where you did try to group by both? Then we can help by explaining where you went wrong.

Comment: As I explained, I sum the prices if they are in same month and type. Doesn't need to any group for this situation?

Comment: Your comment doesn't make sense @Yilmazam. Like I said, if you showed your attempt(s) we can explain why what you tired didn't work. But, to aggregate you have to have a `GROUO BY` clause (or an `OVER`, but that is clearly not what you're after here).

Answer (score 4):

You can specify a list of expressions in the GROUP BY clause

```
SELECT  Month, Type, SUM(Price) AS [Total Price]
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Month, Type
ORDER BY Month, Type
```

In GROUP BY, list all the involved columns, except those that have an aggregate function (SUM, MIN, MAX, AVG etc.) applied to them.